# TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText doesnt work with Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

I want to use `TextInputEditText` and `TextInputLayout` in my app, but it will not work with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. But if I set it to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`, it will work without any issues, but this will destroy all of my styles in app.

Usage in XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/nameLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/reg_edit_text_style"
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    android:hint="@string/name">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/nameEt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:nextFocusDown="@id/lastNameEt"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        style="@style/reg_edit_text_inner_style"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

In `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

Error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:240)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:215)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:143)
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Bridge theme worked

Comment: You can also add those attributes if you want to keep using current appcompat theme, because you're getting theme enforcement errors..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `AppCompat` themes with `MaterialComponents` views.

If you're not ready to completely move to `MaterialComponents` theme, you can use the bridge theme of the same. Although, using the Bridge theme is not a recommended path. In  their official documentation, they say:

> Doing an app-wide migration by changing your app theme to inherit from
>   a Material Components theme is the recommended approach. However, be
>   sure to test thoroughly afterwards, as components in existing layouts
>   may change their looks and behavior.
>
> Note: If you can't change your theme, you can do one of the following:
>
> Inherit from one of our Material Components Bridge themes. See the
>   Bridge Themes section for more details. Continue to inherit from an
>   AppCompat theme and add some new theme attributes to your theme. See
>   the App Compat Themes section for more details.

You can use the Bridge themes of MaterialComponents by adding `.Bridge` in front of `MaterialComponents` theme name.

eg.

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.*.Bridge
```

In your case, it'd be `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge`

**Although,
If you want to keep using the `AppCompat` themes, you need to add following few attributes to your current theme, or it'll throw `Theme Enforcement Error`** which you're getting right now.

```
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/my_app_primary_variant_color</item>
  <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/my_app_secondary_variant_color</item>
  <item name="colorSurface">@color/my_app_surface_color</item>
  <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/my_app_color_on_primary</item>
  <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/my_app_color_on_secondary</item>
  <item name="colorOnBackground">@color/my_app_color_on_background</item>
  <item name="colorOnError">@color/my_app_color_on_error</item>
  <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/my_app_color_on_surface</item>
  <item name="scrimBackground">@color/mtrl_scrim_color</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceHeadline1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline1</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceHeadline2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline2</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceHeadline3">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline3</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceHeadline4">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceHeadline5">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceHeadline6">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceBody1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceBody2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceCaption">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
  <item name="textAppearanceOverline">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Overline</item>
```

You need to add these attributes in your current `AppCompat` theme.